Sort Object.keys map
I have the following:
{Object.keys(categorizedDatas3).map((key, index) => {

categorizedDatas3 looks like this:
{
    "Boat": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Name": "AAA"
            },
            {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Name": "BBB"
            }
        ]
    },
    "4x4": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Name": "CCC"
            }
        ]
    }
}

How can I sort the key A-Z (i.e. I always want 4x4 items to appear before Boat items)?

This question is similar to: Sort JavaScript object by key. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Object.keys(categorizedDatas3).sort().map(...)

@GuyIncognito yes, that works - I thought I needed to define the sort - but does sort() by default sort A-Z?

See what the documentation says

You can use the Array.prototype.sort method to sort the array.
In order to sort the array alphabetically, you can use the String.prototype.localeCompare method.
I took the answer from this other answer. In your case it would be:
{Object.keys(categorizedDatas3)
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .map((key, index) => 
    /* your element */
)}

